# Tengo un inconveniente al traer una imagen de una base de datos SQL server a un api en .net 6

Tags: sql-server, .net-6.0

estoy haciendo un api en .net 6 con una base de datos en SQL server en el cual estoy llamando a un procedimiento almacenado que trae diversos datos de muchas tablas, entre ellas se encuentra una imagen que esta definida como imagen en la tabla como se ve a continuación:

[image: imagen declaración de la imagen en la base de datos]

Cuando llamo el procedimiento almacenado desde la terminal de SQL Server, la respuesta que me da es en formato hexadecimal "creo" y se muestra así:

```
0x424D101800000000000036000000280000002D0 ..... continua
```

Pero cuando lo llamo en el api me manda la siguiente respuesta:

```
Qk0QGAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAALQAAAC0AAAABABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////v7/0szVw728/fv0//
```

Es mas larga la respuesta pero es para dar una ejemplo de como se muestra.

He intentado de cambiar el tipo de dato del modelo a: byte[], Byte[], Image pero genera error, string. pero todos me traen la misma respuesta.

¿alguien sabe que podría hacer? muchas gracias :D

el código que se llama al procedimiento almacenado es:

```
public static DataTable Listar(string nombreProcedimiento, List<ParametroSP> parametros = null)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nombreProcedimiento, conexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (parametros != null)
            {
                foreach (var parametro in parametros)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametro.Nombre, parametro.ValorSTR);
                }
            }
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(tabla);


            return tabla;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
```

y el controlador:

```
public IActionResult listtaDeHaciendas(string codigoPersona) {

        //valido si la persona existe y trigo el id de la persona
        var itenSocio = _repository.GetPersona(codigoPersona);

        if (itenSocio == null)
        {
            _respuestaAPI.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            _respuestaAPI.IsSuccess = false;
            _respuestaAPI.ErrorMessage.Add("No se han encontrado datos");
            return NotFound(_respuestaAPI);
        }
       //creo una lista de los parametros que voy a ingresar al procedimiento almacenado

        List<ParametroSP> tabla = new List<ParametroSP> {
            new ParametroSP("@cId",itenSocio.IdSocio),
            new ParametroSP("@cEstado","N"),
            
        };
        //llamo al procedimiento almacenado
        DataTable dt = DBDatos.Listar("SpGetImagen", tabla);

        if (dt == null)
        {
            _respuestaAPI.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            _respuestaAPI.IsSuccess = false;
            _respuestaAPI.ErrorMessage.Add("No se han encontrado datos");
            return NotFound(_respuestaAPI);
        }

        var jsonElemento = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);


        _respuestaAPI.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        _respuestaAPI.IsSuccess = true;
        _respuestaAPI.Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SpGetImagen>>(jsonElemento);
        return Ok(_respuestaAPI);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se almacenó en la bd? ¿Tienes acceso a dicho proceso?

Comment: no, solo tengo acceso a los procedimientos de traer información, como menciono antes, desde sql server trae esa imagen en este formato:  0x424D101800000000000036000000280000002D0 
pero si hago el llamado desde el api, me trae la información de esta manera:
Qk0QGAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAALQAAAC0AAAABABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////

parece como si fuera basura o no se que pasara

Comment: ¿Has considerado que quizás esa imagen esté como base64? Intenta con esto: `byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);`  donde `base64Data` es el string que tienes como "Qk0QGAAAAAAA...".

Comment: si tienes mucha razón, tarde un poco en darme cuenta pero se convirtió automáticamente a base 64, lo único que tocaba hacer era transformarlo en el front con una etiqueta de conversión y ya mostraba la imagen.... muchas gracias

Comment: En la parte inferior hay una caja de texto **Tu Respuesta** Coloca todo lo que hiciste para dar con la solución a tu escenario, le será de gran ayuda a quienes pasen por lo mismo y/o algo similar, ¡serás el héroe de toda esa gente! Dale, escribe y luego marca como aceptada la respuesta. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a  fredyfx, descubrí que el api trasformaba directamente de arreglo de bytes (o de tipo image en la base de datos) a base64 en el api directamente, lo unico que se tiene que hacer es poner en el front la conversion a base64, en mi caso con angular seria lo siguiente:

En el archivo .ts se traen los datos del api.

En el html, se coloca lo siguiente en la etiqueta img:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
     <h5>Hierro</h5>
     <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{hierroHda1}}"[width]="100">
</div>
```